# Array_pop + WordPress 3.7.1 "get_results" = error?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

This is very odd. I just upgraded to WordPress 3.7.1, and I suddenly began getting the error

```
PHP Warning:  array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in (...)
```

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
$User = array_pop($RM->DB->get_results($RM->DB->prepare(
    'SELECT 
        `user_id` AS `ID`,
        `api_key` AS `key`
    FROM
        `rm_users` 
    WHERE
        user_id = %d'
    , $user_value)));
```

Here I'm using WordPress's $wpdb object to query custom tables. The weird thing is if I change it to this:

```
$Users = $RM->DB->get_results($RM->DB->prepare(
    'SELECT 
        `user_id` AS `ID`,
        `api_key` AS `key`
    FROM
        `rm_users` 
    WHERE
        user_id = %d'
    , $user_value));
$User = array_pop($Users);
```

It works perfectly fine. If array_pop was receiving a null parameter, then it stands that $Users would be null and would cause the same error, but it is not null and it does not cause the error. It is the same way everywhere I use WordPress's "get_results" method along with "array_pop".

Is this a legitimate php bug, or is there some deep mechanic that I'm not aware of that would prevent array_pop from taking the output of a method directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear to be a WP bug as far as I can tell, and I am unsure why it has only started since 3.7.1.

I have run the following on a custom table using both methods you provide, on 3.7.1, and both return a single stdClass object as expected.

```
// Get one out with pop
print_r(array_pop($this->_wpdb->get_results($this->_wpdb->prepare(
    'SELECT
        CONCAT(user.firstname," ",user.surname) AS name,
        user.email,
        user.mobile,
        user.userType
    FROM user
    WHERE userId=%d
    LIMIT 1;',
    $userId))));

// get one out with 2-step
$users = $this->_wpdb->get_results($this->_wpdb->prepare(
    'SELECT
        CONCAT(user.firstname," ",user.surname) AS name,
        user.email,
        user.mobile,
        user.userType
    FROM user
    WHERE userId=%d
    LIMIT 1;',
    $userId));
print_r(array_pop($users));
```

Rather than using pop, use the [get_row method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row):

```
$User = $RM->DB->get_row($RM->DB->prepare(
    'SELECT 
        `user_id` AS `ID`,
        `api_key` AS `key`
    FROM
        `rm_users` 
    WHERE
        user_id = %s'
    , $user_value));
```

Or if you would prefer the result as an associative array rather than an stdClass:

```
$User = $RM->DB->get_row($RM->DB->prepare(
    'SELECT 
        `user_id` AS `ID`,
        `api_key` AS `key`
    FROM
        `rm_users` 
    WHERE
        user_id = %s'
    , $user_value), ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the mystery, but it resolves the issue and reads better so ultimately this is probably the way I should be doing it.